# How implement one-to-many objects database in sqlite for android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm quite new to `SQLite` and `SQL` and I am struggling with how to approach the following:

My app will display a list of community members. If I click a member, I can see a list of posts made by the members. A post is an object with name, time and message. How can I store this in an `SQLite` database so that I can query the database by `userid` and get the list of posts for a specific user.

I have a Users table with these columns:

```
USER_ID | NAME
```

I have a Tweet table with these columns:

```
USER_ID | NAME | TIME | MESSAGE
```

My questions are: what the best approach / structure to `link` these two tables? Do I create a new tweet table for every user, or do I store all tweets in one long table with tweets for user 1 first then for user 2 etc?

I'm not necessarily looking for code dumps but rather an explanation of the logic.

Comment: I would add a `tweet_id` to the Tweet table and then store one row for every tweet.

Comment: You might need to delete a tweet in the future. Terry's approach is more clear doing so, because of the tweet_id

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a typical "JOIN" scenario where you have a one-to-many relationship between Users and Posts.

Here is an example of a query that would display all users and their posts:

```
SELECT u.User_ID, u.Name, p.Time, p.Message
FROM Users u INNER JOIN Posts p ON u.User_ID = p.User_ID
```

This will produce a resultset with four columns.  Each "Tweet" will be displayed with its related User record.  The 'u.' and 'p.' syntax are table aliases used to make the query easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. Do I store all posts from all users in one single Post table or is there a separate Post table for every user?

Comment: @Pierre Normalized databases generally contain one table per "type" of data stored, so there is no need to create additional tables.  You can  add users and related posts to these two tables.

Comment: OK, clear. Many thanks for such a fast, knowledgeable and helpful answer.

Comment: Let say total post are 4 so the above query will return 4 rows each row having `u.Name` (redundant)?

Answer (score 14):

An answer has been given and accepted already, but I wanted to add this.

What you want is one table with users, `users`. In this table you store your user information (`user_id`, `name`).

In your `Tweets` table, store all tweets for all users. One tweet per row. I'm using `tweet_id` as `PRIMARY KEY` for the `Tweets` table.

You can then 'link' the two in code by doing a `JOIN` like Dave Swersky said.

For example:

```
Users
--------------------------
user_id   |   user_name
--------------------------
   123    |    'Terry'
   34     |    'Pierre'

Tweets
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
tweet_id |   user_id   |  time      |         message     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   0     |    123      | 135646     |  'This is a tweet'
   1     |    123      | 132646     |  'This is another tweet by Terry'
   2     |    34       | 352646     |  'Pierre\'s tweet'
```

I'm not sure what `name` is for in your `Tweets` table. As far as I know tweets do not have a name/subject(?). You do **not** need to store the user name in both the `tweets` and `users` table.

For a quick SQLFiddle, go here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43492/1/0

**Join**

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, t.time, t.message, t.time 
FROM my_users u
INNER JOIN tweets t ON u.user_id = t.user_id
```

Comment: This seems to be the best approach!

Comment: @Terry Seidler Many thanks. I'll upvote this when I've earned some more points...And what a great link to sqlfiddle. Superb.

Comment: No problem! Good luck! My 'time' field on SQL fiddle is just a varchar value, but that shouldn't matter ;)

Answer (score 6):

You need to have two tables:

1.**Users**

USER_ID | NAME

2.**TWEETS**

USER_ID | TIME | MESSAGE

Now for the explanation:

Table 1 is represents the users, there is all the data about the user, like name, phone, address etc.

Table 2 is for all the tweets of all the users, and there is a column that connects between user and his tweet.
In table 2 USER_ID is foreign key, that points to exactly one row in the users table.

To get all the tweets for one user, you can write the next query:

```
Select TWEETS.MESSAGE, TWEETS.TIME
from Users, TWEETS
where Users.USER_ID = TWEETS.USER_ID
and Users.NAME = "Pierre";
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. Unfortunately I don't have enough points to up-vote your answer...

Comment: By sidestepping the JOIN keyword, this answers supplies a solution that is applicable in sqlite as well, as hinted at by the OP!